# how to initiate a convex set in matrix given its limit points?

Tags: algorithm, convex

Suppose I have a n-d matrix representing the space and elements set is representing the limit points of a convex set. How to set all elements in this convex set (i.e. pt as convex combination of elements set already) efficiently?

My current approach is to first find the smallest ball includes all limit points. Then find convex hull of current set and remove points that is not the desired limit point. Repeat above step until the convex hull of all set points is the given limit points. However, I think this method is too slow for a large set.